# how do I install internet explorer 11 on windows 11

Tags: internet-explorer, installation, windows-11

I need to install ie11 on win 11.  Only Internet Explorer 11 will work, that is, ie 11 mode in Edge won't work as the active X wont work in Edge, popping up multiple IE11 windows, the way it should.

Comment: What they don't mention is that ActiveX only works in the active window. If you use it to spawn another window, the new window opens in Edge without IE mode. So, all those automation scripts that people, like me, developed don't work

Answer (score -1):

I would like to inform you that you will not be able to install the IE 11 browser on a Windows 11 OS.

You said, 'ie 11 mode in Edge won't work as the active X wont work in Edge'.

I would like to inform you that the IE mode in the Edge browser supports the ActiveX control. You could make a test with it.

[image]

Reference: [IE mode supports the following Internet Explorer functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality)

Please do let me know if I misunderstand something from your description.

Comment: What they don't mention is that Active only works in the active window.  If you use it to spawn another window, the new window opens in Edge without IE mode.  So, all those automation scripts that people, like me, developed don't work.

Comment: You could try to add another windows URL to the Sitelist.XML file. So new window will also get loaded in the IE mode. Further, you need to provide detailed information about the issue. It could give a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Spawning windows is just one of many setting-enabled-features you don't get in edge-ie mode.  To see the others, open IE, click tool-options and you will see there are thousands of other settings.  Too many for me to mention.  If I also include settings that only work while in admin mode then the list doubles.

Comment: If we focus on the main question of this case then I would like to inform you that you will not be able to install and use IE 11 on Windows 11 OS.